# Fetch raw data from Google Analytics or Adobe Analytics in SQL

Tags: sql, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, adobe-analytics

I have been looking around for a way to fetch raw data from Omniture (SiteCatalyst) or Google Analytics in SQL for some Analysis purpose.

Is there a way that i can fetch it from website to SQL or is there any data repository website available that i can directly download raw data from there?
Kindly explain the process if you are aware of any.

Much appreciated!

Comment: You have to fetch the data from Google Analytics API, using C# example and then in you C# application insert the data in SQL database.

Comment: There are a lot of GA API available. The one i got to know for this is BigQuery API. Is this the one you are talking about? And also share some link or some example.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot download raw data from Google Analytics via the API - the API returns aggregated data only. You can export raw data as per the [BigQuery Export scheme](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3437719?hl=en) to BigQuery, but that  requires a GA360 account.

You can override the [sendHitTask](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/tasks) to send data to your own server and store it in a database there (but obviously that requires a lot of resources and does not give you historical data).

Adobe Analytics does allow raw data exports, but that comes at a cost and you have to talk to Client Care.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MS Sql Server and have access to SQL server integration services you could select the data out using a custom task or you could use a scripting task.    Both of these option will be able to handle downloading the data directly from Google analytics and inserting into an SQL server database.

If you are not then your going to have to create your own application for this.   Google analytics data is return in Json format. you will need to covert it yourself into SQL for insert.