# Is connecting to adobe analytics API possible with SISS

Tags: ssis, adobe, adobe-analytics

Is it possible to connect to adobe analytics API using SISS? I am working on an ETL process and was wondering if there was a particular driver to do this...

I have looked at Adobe Analytics documentation and there is not mention of drivers to connect to adobe analytics directly or with its API service.

Comment: I do not know the answer, but to increase your odds of receiving an answer then I suggest that you provide the troubleshooting steps that you have taken to try and first answer the question. For example, did you check with Adobe to see if they have such a driver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not suspect they would make a specific driver for SSIS. Any third party drivers will be questionable from a cost and support stance. You will need to research how to make API calls from SSIS:

[How to make an HTTP request from SSIS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6684317/how-to-make-an-http-request-from-ssis)

https://zappysys.com/blog/loading-data-from-rest-api-to-sql-server-in-ssis/

[Fetch raw data from Google Analytics or Adobe Analytics in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46252146/fetch-raw-data-from-google-analytics-or-adobe-analytics-in-sql)

The last link mentions talking to Adobe Client Care. You might want to see if they have a utility that can export the data to a flat file. That will make your task much easier because then you can build a simple file loader.

Comment: "You might want to see if they have a utility that can export the data to a flat file." Within the Adobe Analytics interface, there is Data Warehouse, which lets you specify dimensions and metrics and have them exported as csv to a designated email or ftp, and you can have it on a recurring schedule.

Comment: @CrayonViolent Thanks for the info - I've never used Adobe Analytics so this is good to know in the event I ever need to. This is definitely a solution that Dip can pursue, especially the FTP part as that can be automated (I am not aware of an automated way to pull data from e-mail).